# Получение значения - экземпляра класса - из Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

Есть экземпляр класса:

```
  class Command
    {
        public string Name;
        public string[] Parameters;

        public Command(string name, params string[] parameters)
        {
            Name = name;
            Parameters = parameters;
        }
    }
```

Также есть словарь, в значения которого попадают экземпляры класса:

```
    static Dictionary<string, Command> Commands = new Dictionary<string, Command>()
    {
        {"start", new Command("start", "engine", "pump") },
        {"power", new Command("power", "engine", "pump") }
    };
```

Как правильно обратиться к словарю, чтобы вытащить значения через `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: Console где у ВАС в словаре?

Comment: @AzizUmarov извините, через консоль. Поправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```
static Dictionary<string, Command> Commands = new Dictionary<string, Command>()
    {
        {"start", new Command("start", "engine", "pump") },
        {"power", new Command("power", "engine", "pump") }
    };

Console.WriteLine(Commands["power"]) // тут объект а что именно из него вам нужно посмотрите сами
```